# ggplot X and O plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I seen this figure and am not very sure how it was generated with the 'x' and 'o' values which are plotted for '1' and '0'.

[image]

Does any body have a clue into how to make this?

Comment: Use `geom_point()` with a `shape=` aesthetic. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make @MrFlick's suggestion a bit more concrete, here's a reprex that comes close to recreating the plot you posted:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(81)
df <- data.frame(x = rexp(200, 1/250), 
                 y = rexp(200, 1/250), 
                 value = c("O", "X"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = value, shape = value)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("dodgerblue", "red")) +
  geom_rug(colour = "gray30", sides = "b") +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3 * 500) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of documentation on `geom_point()` points's shapes, for example [here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-point-shapes-best-tips/).
Happy reading!

[image]